# Nginx rewrite url only works on root

Tags: web, nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;
    error_page 404 /?404;
    error_page 403 /?404;

    location / {
        autoindex off;
        root   c:/webserver/html;
        index  default.asp index.php default.html;
        rewrite ^/([^/]*)$ /?action=$1 break;
    }
```

I got lines of code in my nginx.conf.
this rewrite url works perfect on localhost but when I installed nginx on my vps and tried to reach from pc it doesn't work.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change that :

```
server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
```

with your domain name or server ip.

Then, you must restart our Nginx server for these changes to be recognized.